# Using gform_after_submission with gform_notification

Tags: php, wordpress, gravityforms

I am trying to use gform_after_submission to grab a field value(url of a file) then pass the value to a notification so it can be sent as an attachment. This is what I have so far:

```
add_action("gform_after_submission", "after_submission", 10, 2);
function after_submission($entry, $form){
    $pdf = $entry["3"];
    return $pdf;
}

add_filter( 'gform_notification_3', 'add_notification_attachments', 10, 3 );
function add_notification_attachments( $notification, $form, $entry ) {
    if ( $notification['name'] == 'Admin Notification' ) {
        $path = 'path/to/file.pdf';
        $notification['attachments'] = array( $path );
    }
    return $notification;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Dave, couldn't see your updated code but here's what I managed to do once you told me about converting the URL to a path & it now works perfectly:

```
    function get_file_path_from_url( $file_url ){
   return realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . parse_url( $file_url, PHP_URL_PATH ));
}

add_filter( 'gform_notification_3', 'add_notification_attachments', 10, 3 );
function add_notification_attachments( $notification, $form, $entry ) {
    if ( $notification['name'] == 'Admin Notification' ) {
        $path = $entry['3'];
        $path = get_file_path_from_url($path);
        $notification['attachments'] = array( $path );
    }
    return $notification;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but you shouldn't need the first action, only the notification filter.

```php
add_filter( 'gform_notification_3', 'add_notification_attachments', 10, 3 );
function add_notification_attachments( $notification, $form, $entry ) {
    if ( $notification['name'] == 'Admin Notification' ) {
        $path = $entry['3'];
        $notification['attachments'] = array( $path );
    }
    return $notification;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dave,

I tried the above but it didn't work, tried replacing $entry['3'] with a regular url and the file still didn't get attached, any ideas what's going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I assumed based on your code that $entry['3'] already had the actual file path. I've updated to the code above to show you how to convert a file URL to a path.